# How do I generate a list of random strings and hashes and output it in an HTML table?

Tags: php, html, hash, sha256

I'm trying to generate a list of, let's say 10, random strings and it's SHA-256 hash in an HTML table.

I have found the following code submitted by another user to generate the random string:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}
```

How do I loop the function and how do I output the string and the hash of the string in an HTML table?

Comment: *"and output it in a table?"* - what kind of table; html? mysql? table for 2?

Comment: no response. well, wait for someone who knows what you're asking, because I for one, don't.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I thought adding the HTML tag would be clear enough that I meant a HTML table.

Comment: Got it. I made a slight edit ;-) I see similar questions like this, only to find out they want to enter the generated hash in a database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
function generate($length)
{
    $string = '';
    if($length > 128)
    {
        $string .= generate($length-128);
    }
    else
    {
        $string = substr(hash('sha512',mt_rand()),0,$length);
    }
    return $string;
}

$table = '<table>%s</table>';
$item = '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>';
$res = '';
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $str = generate(10);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $str);

    $res .= sprintf($item, $hash, $str);
}

echo sprintf($table, $res);
```